# Quotes surely. Cryptogram #2

Tags: cipher

Answers **must include method of encryption** along with plain text and explanation (explanation refers to thoughts or clues that made you think to do certain things).

---

### Cryptogram #2

> kbemzkbedje de emz drqdelzrebefz dreenfkzre ak bff lmdedjbf nzezbnjm.

---

**Hint:**

> Kashmir, $-1/12$

Comment: Does this rely on solving #1? (I had a quick look at the comments and edit history.)

Comment: @randal'thor I couldn't edit deleted post so I undeleted it first and changed the puzzle. It actually has no link to that apart from some very common things.

Comment: I believe it is a substitution cipher. But tell me: were all the mistakes made on purpose to mislead us?

Comment: @mmking maybe. maybe not.

Comment: I think I've got it. But can you explain what you mean by "Kashmir" and what it has to do with the puzzle?

Comment: @mmking cashmir forces? zeta(-1)=-1/12? physics? maths?

Answer (score 4):

> Mathematics is the indispensable instrument of all physical research.
>   - by Marcellin Berthelot

It is a substitution cipher.

```
The cipher letters:    k b e m z d j r q l f n a
                       -------------------------
The plaintext letters: m a t h e i c n d p l r o
                       f   s     y         m
```

A few of the letters stand for two letters. For the words containing that letter, the decoded letter must be alternated.

For instance, letter k stands for both m and f. The first word, the fifth word, and the sixth word in the ciphertext all have k in it. So in the first word, k stands for m. In the fifth word, k stands for f, and in the sixth word, k stands for m.

Comment: you're missing the link,i.e. a function that  tells us the substitution mapping.

Comment: I don't understand where you derived your cipher text from. Can you explain its origin, or was it just trial and error?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Do you mean why I thought it was a substitution cipher? I plugged it into [Quipqiup](http://www.quipqiup.com) and got something about mathematics and research. Given that it actually made a little sense, I figured out the rest.

Comment: something like f(b)=a. What is f?

Comment: @mmking, no, I was curious how you came up with the cypher mapping. The cypher mapping is not evident to me just by reading the puzzle text. Is the cypher mapping described by the hint? How did you know to map k->m, for example? Did you just paste the string into quipquip and then brute force a solution, or was there something specific that lead you to use the cypher that you have found?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I didn't get anything from the hint. From quipqiup, it's given that the first word was mathematics and the last word was research. So I mapped the first few letters. The result was "mathematics it the i--it-e-tat-e  i-tt--me-s  -m  a--  -hitical research". a-- looked like all to me, and from googling I guessed that -hitical was probably physical. I complained above about how many mistakes there were in the ciphertext. Turns out, some of the letters represent multiple letters.

Comment: @ADG What kind of function are you looking for? Does it involve converting the letters to something else? And technically you can't call it a function because sometimes you have two outputs for one input.

Comment: nope a function can be many-one. It has something to do with f(letter_index) where letter index of z is 25 and of c is 3

Comment: @ADG z is 25, not 26?

Comment: yes a typo maybe. z is 26 but that doesn't matter since we can find g(x)=f(x-1) or f(x)=g(x+!)

Comment: Also dcode.fr finds out good approximations: MATHEMATIST IT THE INDITWENTATLE INTTRLMENT OM ALL WHITISAL RETEARSH.  and MATHEMATICT IT THE INDITSENTATLE INTTRLMENT PM ALL SHITICAL RETEARCH.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the excellent answer by @mmking:

First, recover the key for the **polyphonic substitution cipher**:

```
Plain:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Cipher: BEJQZK MD  FKRAL NEEF   D
```

Second, rewrite the key, replacing each letter with its index in the standard alphabet:

```
Plain:   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
Cipher:  1  4  9 16 25 10  ? 12  3  ?  ?  5 10 17  0 11  ? 13  4  4  5  ?  ?  ?  3  ?
```

Notice the familiar sequence of squares at the beginning, and assume the key is derived from the sequence of square numbers modulo 26:

```
Plain:          0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
Cipher:         1    4    9   16   25   10    ?   12    3    ?    ?    5   10   17    0   11    ?   13    4    4    5    ?    ?    ?    3    ?
Squares mod:    1    4    9   16   25   10   23   12    3   22   17   14   13   14   17   22    3   12   23   10   25   16    9    4    1    0
Squares:        1    4    9   16   25   36   49   64   81  100  121  144  169  196  225  256  289  324  361  400  441  484  529  576  625  676
```

That doesn't quite work. But wait: Notice the `4 9 16 25` at the beginning, and the `5 10 17 0` in the middle, ten places later. Next, assume the key is derived from the two digits of the letter's index:

```
cipher = (plain % 10) ** 2 + (plain // 10)) 
cipher %= 26

Plain:      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
Cipher:     1    4    9   16   25   10    ?   12    3    ?    ?    5   10   17    0   11    ?   13    4    4    5    ?    ?    ?    3    ?
Formula:    1    4    9   16   25   10   23   12    3    1    2    5   10   17    0   11   24   13    4    2    3    6   11   18    1   12
```

Still a few incorrect letters towards the end. Assume the tens digit is also squared to finally reproduce the key:

```
cipher = (plain % 10) ** 2 + (plain // 10) ** 2
cipher %= 26

Plain:      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
Cipher:     1    4    9   16   25   10    ?   12    3    ?    ?    5   10   17    0   11    ?   13    4    4    5    ?    ?    ?    3    ?
Formula:    1    4    9   16   25   10   23   12    3    1    2    5   10   17    0   11   24   13    4    4    5    8   13   20    3   14
```

Curiously, this formula uses a 1-indexed alphabet to find the value for the plain letter, but outputs cipher letters using a 0-indexed alphabet.

Comment: "Edrjz emz lnbjedjz ak jndlebrbfdede de br bne, kbemzkbedjbf bllnabjmze jbrrae bfnbde ez zulzjezq ea ddzfq b eaffedar dr jndleafaxd, ezjbfez bne jbr brq kfee enbrejzrq emz jafq faxdj ak ejdzredkdj kzemaq." - WFF & LDC